# Is it possible to transfer files to a powered off device?

Tags: boot, file-transfer, lg

Unfortunately, I have managed to delete an integral directory of the phone, which causes it to stuck on the boot-up screen.
It would be very easy to repair this damage if I could find out how to mount phone's internal memory, the root directory, to transfer over any files missing.

Is it possible to do this with a powered-off device?

This in an Android 4.1.2 stock, LG Optimus E440 (L4 II) of unknown bootloader status (I don't even know if this phone has an unlockable bootloader o.O).

Furthermore, I've discovered of this "LGMobile Support Tool" Windows program, is it a legitimate LG software, and would it do something to help me?

Comment: What is the device - care to embellish your question to include *ALL* info, such as Android version, rooted, locked bootloader status, etc, please provide as much info as you can in order for us to help you.

Comment: I really have no idea about the bootloader, but I do have a rooted LG Optimus LG E440 (L4 II), stock ROM.

Comment: In that case, please re-edit your question to include that information as it will get overlooked easily especially if there's going to be a lot of comments below the question :)

Comment: @t0mm13b Okay, done!

Answer (score 0):

No, the phone is powered off, so no activities would be running to enable a transfer of files.

You need to have it powered on.

Comment: Well, does a stuck in the boot-up logo screen count as powered-on?

Comment: If its stuck on the boot screen, there's a potential problem as the adb's service on the phone may not be activated *this is required so that when you plug in the usb cable, the PC will recognize it*.

Comment: What about recovery/fastboot mode? I never played with those, but wouldn't it potentially be possible to access all data that way (provided the device successfully boots into one of them)?

Comment: @Izzy (Hiya _o/) uhmmm... if recovery can access and mount the `/system` partition, although the OP stated its Stock android, so would be safe to say that recovery is stock, but may not have root privileges to do so..? As for fastboot mode, maybe, it would require a stock image to be flashed - might run into the risk of b0rking up the device, LG are a bit funny that way..

Comment: @t0mm13b \o_ re-hi! Yupp, stock makes that tricky here, I've missed that fact. And LG... well, a special case (ask me! with my P880...) So right you are, unlikely in that constellation. Still, was worth a guess. Thanks for the details!